# StageWebView in Flex 4.6 does not load content via Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, apache-flex, stagewebview

I am developing a mobile app with HTML/JS/PHP, and I'm using flex StageWebView for app host.
I'm using Ajax for "More Posts..." Button that trying to load more posts without refreshing page, but it does not work in flex StageWebView,and i show StageWebView After The Page Loaded Compeletly.

in Browsers and Android webView it works fine.
any ideas?

JS:

```
function loadFeed(start, filter) {
$('#more_messages').html('<div class="load_more"><div class="preloader-retina-large preloader-center"></div></div>');

if(filter == '') {
    q = '';
} else {
    q = '&filter='+filter;
}

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "requests/load_feed.php",
    data: "start="+start+q, 
    cache: false,
    success: function(html) {
        $('#more_messages').remove();

        // Append the new comment to the div id
        $('#messages').append(html);

        // Reload the timeago plugin
        jQuery("div.timeago").timeago();

        autosize();
    }
});
}
```

Flex:

```
protected function addedToStageHandler(event:Event):void
        {

            webView = new StageWebView();
            webView.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onWebViewComplete);
            webView.addEventListener(ErrorEvent.ERROR,onWebViewError);
            webView.addEventListener(LocationChangeEvent.LOCATION_CHANGE,onWebViewLocationChange);
            webView.addEventListener(LocationChangeEvent.LOCATION_CHANGING,onWebViewLocationChanging);

            webView.viewPort = new Rectangle(0,0,stage.stageWidth,stage.stageHeight);
            trace(webView.location);
            webView.loadURL("URL");
        }

        protected function onWebViewComplete(event:Event):void
        {
            trace("Complete!");
            webView.stage = this.stage;
        }
```

Comment: I honestly don't have a clue why you would want to do that. There are tools like PhoneGap to package html/js as native apps. Why use StageWebView to do that job, knowing that you'll have very limited functionalities and will run into issues like these and require the user to load a 500kb framework just to display a trimmed down browser?

Comment: because i cant download PhoneGap:
"npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
and is related to network connectivity.
In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.". i dont use Proxy and i'm good in Flex.

Comment: Solved. there was a some errors in my JS, my bad!

Comment: @user3118109 so your .ajax settings (data, sucess, cache, etc.) were all ok and didnt require any changes?  im using stagewebview with jquery to load some json and works fine in browsers just not in stagewebview - and im trying to track down the issue.  also tried switching to .getJSON but same result.  just trying to find some clues and was curious about how you fixed your ajax post problem.  thanks!

Comment: sorry its late but late better that never! yes everything was fine just a error in js.